# How to prevent a Samsung Galaxy S4 from auto-restarting?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, boot-loop

My Samsung Galaxy S4 auto restarts.

- I removed Battery , SIM card , SD Card for over 1-2 hour, and replaced but the device still auto restart.
- I tried " Home"+ "Volume Down" + "Power" and saw the message "Warning! Critical Problem". I had to choose "Continue Or Cancel". However, choosing Continue or Cancel has no effect.

Any idea why this auto restart is happening? Can any software format the device using computer? I can't open my phone now, because when I plug the battery the device auto restart.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get into the recovery. You can access it by pressing Volume UP + Power Button. When your screen turns on, release the Power Button. 
If you can get into the recovery without constant restarting problems, you can make a "factory reset". This will delete all your data and settings but might solve.

But as a side note: Try to provide more information. When did it start turning itself on/off? What apps did you install before? What is your android version and is your device rooted or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can boot into recovery mode and select "Wipe cache partition". This will clear your device's cached data without harming your personal data. Sometimes, your device may behave unexpectedly due to corrupt cache data. If this doesn't help, you need to perform a factory reset from the recovery mode.